# How can I identify a type of wood

Tags: wood-identification, wood

I have a piece of wood and I was trying to figure out what the type was for example: Oak, Pine or maybe even the specific species given enough characteristics.

What tools or resources could I use to help determine this.

Comment: Wording could be improved. English was never my strong point.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Forgot that one was there. Maybe we can merge these.

Comment: I had forgotten about that other case, but I agree this is a duplicate.

Comment: Should I just delete this question and move the answer then @rob

Comment: I suppose that might be cleanest, though it's up to you. Man, your answer is really on the move today!

Comment: Moved my answer and flagged as dup in case new users find it.

Comment: It *is* a good question!